# How to do nasm-like structs in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, struct, nasm, cl.exe

is there some way to define static structure that is already one and only instance of itself?
Like the way you can do it with the struc keyword in nasm?

Comment: like `struct { int x, y } point;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an anonymous structure, like this:

```
struct {
   int memberA, memberB;
} my_struct;

my_struct.memberA = 1;
my_struct.memberB = 2;

printf("%d %d\n", my_struct.memberA, my_struct.memberB);
```

Comment: @stupid_idiot it's not the struct tag. it's the identifier of the object which you are creating. the struct type has no tag in this case.

Comment: i figured for compile time initialization you can use = {{},{},..}; which well.. ugly but accepted by compiler. is there perhaps some nicer way to do it? prefereably so it has the form .member = value?

Comment: @Pyjong: GNU C supports `{ .fieldA = value, .fieldB = value }` **designated initializer** syntax for structs, but I think that's [a GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) since the GNU C manual doesn't normally bother to document features that ISO C already has (except sometimes when they're a C99 feature that's a GNU extension to C++ or C89)

Comment: @Pyjong: Oh, actually looks like ISO C99 does have designated initializers for aggregates (unions and structs): https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization